# Passing macros as kvoptions to listing package commands does not work

Tags: listings, kvoptions

I would like to save chosen `listings` style to a variable `\mlstyle` and use it later in some commands or definitions.

However, while:

```
\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{a.mat}
```

a version that I expected to use:

```
\newcommand{\mlstyle}{Matlab-editor} 
\lstinputlisting[style=\mlstyle]{a.mat}
```

does not.

> Package Listings Error:
>   **style Matlab-editor undefined**.
>   \lstinputlisting[style=\mlstyle]{a.mat}

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents} % only need to provide the file a.mat

\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\newcommand{\mlstyle}{Matlab-editor}%{Matlab-bw}%{Matlab-Pyglike}

\begin{filecontents*}{a.mat}
    a = 1;
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{a.mat} % WORKS

%\lstinputlisting[style=\mlstyle]{a.mat} % DOES NOT WORK

\end{document}
```

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Most key-value interfaces do not expandthe values given as options

Comment: 'Simple' solution: `\expandafter\lstinputlisting\expandafter[\mlstyle]{a.mat}` where `\mlstyle` is `style=Matlab-editor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `listings` parses options, it generally does no expansion, but we can coerce it to do it for `style`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mat}
    a = 1;
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \lst@Key{style}\relax{%
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
      \noexpand\lst@LAS{style}{sty}{[]{#1}}%
    }\x\lst@NoAlias\lststylefiles
    \lsthk@SetStyle{}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mlstyle}{Matlab-editor}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{\jobname.mat}

\lstinputlisting[style=\mlstyle]{\jobname.mat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's an expansion issue. I suggest making `\mlstyle` into a macro. For example, if you define

```
\newcommand{\mlstyle}[2][editor]{\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-#1]{#2}}
```

then you can use:

```
\mlstyle{a.mat} % DOES WORK with style = Matlab-editor
\mlstyle[bw]{a.mat} % DOES WORK with style = Matlab-bw
\mlstyle[Pyglike]{a.mat} % DOES WORK with style = Matlab-Pyglike
```

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents} % only need to provide the file a.mat

\usepackage{listing}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
% usage: \mlstyle[matlab style]{filename}
% where the default matlab style is Matlab-editor
% and \mlstyle[X]{filename} uses style=Matlab-X
\newcommand{\mlstyle}[2][editor]{\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-#1]{#2}}

\begin{filecontents*}{a.mat}
    a = 1;
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[style=Matlab-editor]{a.mat} % WORKS

\mlstyle{a.mat} % DOES WORK with style = Matlab-editor
\mlstyle[bw]{a.mat} % DOES WORK with style = Matlab-bw
\mlstyle[Pyglike]{a.mat} % DOES WORK with style = Matlab-Pyglike

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It works if you use lowercase letters in the style name:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents} % only need to provide the file a.mat

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\newcommand{\mlstyle}{matlab-editor}%

\begin{filecontents*}{a.mat}
    a = 1;
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[style=\mlstyle]{a.mat} % 

\end{document}
```